# Is there a usable HTML web gallery template for Lightroom 2?

Tags: templates, image-gallery, adobe-lightroom

The built-in HTML gallery unfortunately generates invalid HTML markup so its looks are likely more coincidence than proper design. That aside its JavaScript usage prevents using the middle mouse button to open an image in a new tab.

A look at the few free HTML gallery templates out there shows me that there seems to be little interest in building an actual HTML gallery which doesn't use JavaScript. Most of them are using JS to build fancy animations or in-page popup boxes containing the image. This may be nice for some people but at least one person who looks at my images is on dial-up and quickly opening all images in individual tabs to let them load and then close the connection is very nice to have there.

Anyone seen such a gallery template; i. e. simple, plain HTML without JS? My HTML/CSS skills aren't that good that I can develop such a thing on my own, unfortunately.

Comment: @Johannes, help me out.  websites & services are offtopic here, so this largely appears offtopic.  it may be appropriate to http://doctype.com/ but doesn't seem appropriate to Stack Overflow.  if this is about a template for (or feature of) Adobe Lightroom, or one of its plugins, then i think we can consider this on-topic.  please clarify so this doesn't get closed incorrectly (or so that it gets closed correctly if it should be).

Comment: I am searching for a web gallery template for Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 2. So it's about a packaged piece of stuff for a computer program for managing and post-processing photos. It's not web- or server-related, that's merely the target of what said thing does.In particular: http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/features/allfeatures/index.html#showcase

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification.  sounds on-topic to me.

Comment: Photographers generally know as much about web design as Adobe engineers, and there are so many gallery generating software packages out there that there's just not a lot of demand for such a thing.